# If + past simple + would have + p.p

Tags: conditional-constructions

I was reading my English book when I suddenly read this sentence: "If I had a digital camera, I would have taken some pictures".

If the sentence isn't wrong, can someone explain which conditional type this is? [image]

Answer (score 3):

[Conditionals:](http://www.ef.com/english-resources/english-grammar/conditional/)

*"If I had a digital camera, I would have taken some pictures"* is an example of the so-called 'mixed conditional'.

> In this type of conditional, we use the past perfect or the  simple past  in the if  clause and the  present conditional or the perfect conditional in the main clause.
>
> > "If I had a digital camera, I would have taken some pictures". (= I
> >     did not have a digital camera, so I could not take any photos).
>
> If you weren't afraid of spiders, you would have picked it up and put
>   it outside.

Comment: But why is the if clause in the past tense?! Shouldn't it be in past perfect?

Answer (score 2):

*If I had a digital camera, I would have taken some pictures*.

If the situation expressed in the protasis is understood as permanent (or relatively so), i.e. it relates to past and present time and is ongoing, then it is possible to use a modal preterite like "had", while using the perfect in the apodosis.

Examples like *If Ed spoke French, he would have translated the letter for you* and *If I enjoyed Shakespeare, I would have gone with you* are fine.

So if you didn't have a digital camera at the time when you might have taken some pictures, and that situation still holds at the time of writing, then your example is fine.

Answer (score 1):

The *if* clause is in the past simple tense because it speaks of a true/false moment, a watershed event: I had a camera / I had no camera. In this case, I had no camera, signaled by the opening word *if*. The sentence says that the reason I did not take pictures is directly due to my state of 'no camera.'

Without a camera, how could I take even a single picture? I could not. However, if I had a camera (one switch from no to yes), I would then have been able to take not just one picture, but many.  That opportunity would last over a long period, when I *would have taken* many pictures (as a long process).